# How to create boundary in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form and a list. I want to put them inside a parent component (a boundary) and I want to change their form and behavior based on the detection of the presence of the boundary.

Here's my idea:

```
const ParentChildrenPage = () => {
    return <ParentChildren>
         <ParentForm />
         <ChildrenList />
    </ParentChildren>
}
```

Here are some notes:

1. `ParentForm` when rendred by itself, has a `Cancel` button that returns the user to the previous page. But when it's rendered inside the `ParentChildren` it should not show that `Cancel` button, and on `Save` it should not navigate user to the previous page, but should stay in that page.
2. `ChildrenList` has a `Add` button on top of it. When shown by itself it navigates user to a child creation form. But when it detects that it's rendered inside `ParentChildren` its `Add` button should show a dialog form.

Basically, I'm trying to create the notion of **boundary** and let children components detect that they are rendered inside that boundary and adjust their structure and behavior accordingly.

How can I do this?

Comment: I hope I understand it correctly, but wouldn't it be simple to just have a prop that acts as a flag (on both components, which defaults to false) and to render the component accordingly to the flag? (eg: `<ParentForm hasBoundary/>`, where `const ParentForm = ({hasBoundary = false}) => ...`
If I did not understand it correctly please let me know

Comment: @MariusFlorescu, it's a simple demo of a much more complex requirement. Of course for two components and for one usage, passing props is the best way. But for many components in many different places, it's better to have a boundary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's consider a `Boundary.js` component

```
import React from 'react'

const BoundaryComponent = ({children}) => {
  const childrenWithBoundary = React.Children.map(children, child => {
    if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
      return React.cloneElement(child, { hasBoundary: true });
    }
    return child;
  });

  return childrenWithBoundary
}

export default BoundaryComponent
```

What we do, we iterate through all the children, clone the element and also append a new prop to them.

So, let's create three components, two of them having the possibility to render based on the boundary, and one independent.

```
export const Component1 = ({hasBoundary=false}) => {
  if (hasBoundary) {
    return <div>Component 1 With Boundary</div>
  }
  return <div>Component 1</div>
}

export const Component2 = ({hasBoundary=false}) => {
  if (hasBoundary) {
    return <div>Component 2 With Boundary</div>
  }
  return <div>Component 2</div>
}

export const Component3 = () => {
  return <div>Component 3</div>
}
```

Such that in our `App.js`, we will have:

```
import BoundaryComponent from './Boundary'
import {Component1, Component2, Component3} from './Components'

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1/>
      <Component2/>
      <Component3/>

      <BoundaryComponent>
        <Component1/>
        <Component2/>
        <Component3/>
      </BoundaryComponent>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output:
[image]

****Note:****
In this scenario, the `BoundaryComponent` should have the affected components as direct children.